# custom authorization for ASP.NET Core MVC Application

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm following the Microsoft documentation and I've officially built my own web application (well the bare minimum of the application at least).

Just to give a little context to the question, my app is a deck builder.  The database has a Deck table where the appropriate information is stored when a deck is created.

I created the app with the "individual user accounts" option checked, and an ApplicationUser model was generated (the class contains no code).

I want each deck that is saved to the database to be linked to a user account.  What's the simplest way to go about this?  Should I use "Identity"?

I'd prefer the most simple solution, so that I really understand the basis and then grow from there rather than have a bunk of code chucked at me.  Thanks guys!

Found the answer and marked as duplicate.  (I'm using cookie middleware for authentication)

Comment: Add ApplicationUser  foreign key in Deck table and mark it as unique key.

Comment: That's all?  Even though I may want to do it later, no further customization of the code is necessary?